# Hibernate envers Enumeration audit exception

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Using JBoss Envers (4.2.0 FINAL) annotation but failed when try to audit @Enumerated property

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class TestEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(name="status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusEnum status;

    public enum StatusEnum {
        ACTIVE, INACTIVE, DELETED
    }
}
```

And also in entityManager setting the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" is "update"
When the application startup exceptions below showed:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue$ParameterTypeImpl cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String at
>   org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.BasicMetadataGenerator.addBasic(BasicMetadataGenerator.java:70)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addValueInFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:176)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addValue(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:242)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addProperties(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:258)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:494)
>
> ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your pom file, make sure that hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate-core, and hibernate-envers are on the same version. It is a compatibility issue.

Comment: Thank you it's working, there is compatible issue with my hibernate dependencies, after make sure they are all 4.2.0.Final version everything works.